# Using openssl_pkcs12_export_to_file()

Tags: php, openssl

So I have read the PHP manual ([HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs12-export-to-file.php)) but I'm not sure if it's does exactly what I think it is supposed to do. I need to convert a PFX certificate to a PEM. My question is, does either the above mentioned method or the openssl_pkcs12_export() method do what I need, or does it simply just export the information of the pkcs12 file?

To complete what I need to do, would I need to use the exec() method and use the appropriate openssl command, such as the one listed below:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.cer -nodes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken in your needs... You are just slightly off...

```
pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.pem -clcerts
```

You may also need to

```
pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out ca-certificate.pem -cacerts
```

`-clcerts` is only for client certificates

`-cacerts` is for non-client

Comment: You can convert directly from PFX to PEM? From my understanding you had to go from PFX to CER (or something similar), then to PEM. Also, I take it that the PHP methods won't work then? the export ones.

Comment: I've never tried the PHP method so I can comment, but I don't see why it con't work so long as the script has permissions to write the files.  But yes, I've done direct `pfx` to `pem` conversion using this method on `Ubuntu` OS using `openssl`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll give it a try tomorrow. It's been quite stressful for me, as this isn't my normal element to play in.

Comment: Hope it works out for you.  Good luck!  Look at your specific application, and be sure to note the `node` flags on the end.  `-clcerts` and `-cacerts`

Comment: I'll be sure to keep that in mind. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know if I can point to the file location of the input file, and give the output file a destination? Such as this:

`openssl pkcs12 -in $target_file -out temp/cert.pem` 

Where $target_file is where the input file is, and temp/ is where the output will go.

Comment: start with a backslash and dig all the way down, yes ..  ie `/etc/my/cert/directory/cert.pem`